# Dynamically using array values as API POST parameters in Powershell

Tags: powershell, api, data-structures

i'm trying to create an API to create azure groups using powershell, and i've hit a bit of a dead end. I need to dynamically create multiple groups with varying members per group, but it seems that I cannot just pass the array to the API Request body. Each array value should be enclosed in double quotes like here:

```
$membersArray = "johnp.com","RIF@gmail.com", "aao@gmail.com", "imz@gmail.com"
Write-Host "$($membersArray)"
[string[]]$testArr ="allen@gmailcom", "JohnMartin@gmail.com"
$Method="Post"
$Header = @{"content-type"="application/json";
"Authorization"="Bearer $token"}
$Body =@"
{
    "Tenant":"organization.onmicrosoft.com",
    "Group": "TEST_GROUP_MADE_BY_ALLEN7",
    "ApplicationId" : "", 
    "DelegatedServiceId": "",
    "Owners":["$($testArr[0])", "$($testArr[1])"],
    "Members": ["$($membersArray)"],
    "Description":"test can be deleted for group creation",
    "ResultFormat": "json"
}
"@

$Result =Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL -Method $Method -Headers $Header -Body $Body 
$result.RawContent
$Result.StatusCode
```

**I've redacted the URL endpoint, and the right tenant name, as this is for my corporate work, and this is my test script before applying it to the loop i've made that gets the input data from csv files.**

If we print out the $Body variable, we will get this:

```
Write-Host "$Body" 
{
    "Tenant":"organization.onmicrosoft.com",
    "Group": "TEST_GROUP_MADE_BY_ALLEN7",
    "ApplicationId" : "", 
    "DelegatedServiceId": "",
    "Owners":["allen@gmailcom", "JohnMartin@gmail.com"],
    "Members": ["johnp.com RIF@gmail.com aao@gmail.com imz@gmail.com"],
    "Description":"test can be deleted for group creation",
    "ResultFormat": "json"
}
```

If we look at the Members parameter of the $Body object, the array values are not separated by double quotes and a comma, like so: "arrayValue", "arrayValue2".

So my question is this: Is there any way to do this without using a switch case statement because each group has varying members from 10-45, and if I brute force this with a switch statement it would make the script completely unreadable, and could cause a lot of human error in the development of the script. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seem to got it. This part of the code sets the variable $Body to a JSON:

```
$Body =@"
{
    "Tenant":"organization.onmicrosoft.com",
    "Group": "TEST_GROUP_MADE_BY_ALLEN7",
    "ApplicationId" : "", 
    "DelegatedServiceId": "",
    "Owners":["$($testArr[0])", "$($testArr[1])"],
    "Members": ["$($membersArray)"],
    "Description":"test can be deleted for group creation",
    "ResultFormat": "json"
}
"@
```

So to fix it you have to set the $Body variable to a normal hashtable by removing the ***" before the { and at the closing curly bracket }@ and setting the values in their proper syntax*** like this:

```
$Body = @{    
    "Tenant"="organization.onmicrosoft.com"
    "Group"= "TEST_GROUP_MADE_BY_ALLEN8"
    "ApplicationId" = ""
    "DelegatedServiceId"= ""
    "Owners"= $testArr
    "Members"= $membersArray
    "Description"="test can be deleted for group creation"
    "ResultFormat"= "json"
    }
```

Afterwards we have to create another variable that will hold the data of $body and then convert it to Json so that we can use that as our API Post Body, like so:

```
$JSON= $Body | ConvertTo-Json
#The result of this will be this:
Write-Host $JSON
#Result of Write-Host $JSON

{
    "Owners":  [
                   "allen@gmail.com",
                   "John@gmail.com"
               ],
    "ApplicationId":  "",
    "Group":  "TEST_GROUP_MADE_BY_ALLEN8",
    "DelegatedServiceId":  "",
    "ResultFormat":  "json",
    "Description":  "test can be deleted for group creation",
    "Members":  [
                    "john@gmail.com",
                    "RIF@gmail.com",
                    "aao@gmail.com",
                    "ilmz@gmail.com"
                ],
    "Tenant":  "organization.onmicrosoft.com"
}
#Just use it like so:

$Result =Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL -Method $Method -Headers $Header -Body $JSON
$Result.StatusCode
```

Then we can use this in our loops,etc to dynamically use arrays as parameters to the body of our API Post Requests.